# Изменить изображение в Android

Tags: java, android, обработка-изображений

Всем привет! 
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: как изменить готовое изображение (фотографию), нарисовать на ней текст (в моем случае мне нужно вставить дату и время) и затем сохранить это изображение в файловой системе устройства.
Само изображение загружаю так: `Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);`
Как рисовать на нем и затем сохранить его не знаю. В интернете особо толкового не нашел...

Comment: https://www.skoumal.net/en/android-how-draw-text-bitmap/ Сам когда-то по этой ссылке рисовал на bitmap

Comment: Вероятно есть более какой то оптимальный вариант? Или этот способ тоже может работать с большими изображениями?